# Getting error while running Selenium web-driver test case in safari browser using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

While running Selenium web-driver test case in safari browser getting this Message on the Safari Browser:

```
SafariDriver Launcher
[  0.135s] [safaridriver.client] Connecting to SafariDriver browser extension...
[  0.140s] [safaridriver.client] Extension logs may be viewed by clicking the Selenium [✓] button on the Safari toolbar
[  0.209s] [safaridriver.client] Connected to extension
[  0.210s] [safaridriver.client] Requesting extension connect to client at ws://localhost:45679
```

Safari Browser Version: 5.1.7
Selenium Safari driver version: selenium-safari-driver-2.43.1
But my test case does not run, Only this message shown on the Safari browser.

On the Console get this error:

java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat Testingplace.safaritestcase.testTabs(safaritestcase.java:38)

Comment: Are you sure that is an error?!

Comment: which error are you getting?

Comment: No, above is the message those i get on the safari browser

Comment: there is no question here... not to mention, there's no information "for" a question.. please revise your question with specific details of how you are launching, what versions you are using, etc

Comment: Safari Browser Version: 5.1.7 , 

Selenium Safari driver version: selenium-safari-driver-2.43.1

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Selenium 2 with older version of Safari, I would suggest you to cross check the added Safari Extension is enabled under 'Safari > Preferences'.